# Adding a key to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python and I suspect that the answer to this is fairly simple but I can't seem to find it despite numerous searches.

I am trying to add a key/value to a list of dictionaries.   So I have the following

```
John = ['smith', 'brown', 'wilson']
Details = [{'age': 23, 'hometown': 'chicago'},{'age': 26, 'hometown': 'New York'}, {'age': 44, 'hometown': 'Boston'}]

combined = zip(John, Details)
```

Note: I can be certain that the 2 lists correlate with each other.  However that creates a list of tuples with the first element of each tuple being a string and the second being a dictionary.  What I want is to create a list of dictionaries that has the following format.

```
combined = [{'John': 'smith','age': 23, 'hometown': 'chicago'} , {'John': 'brown', 'age': 23, 'hometown': 'chicago'} ,  {'John': 'wilson', 'age': 44, 'hometown': 'Boston'}]
```

I can't really figure out a way to write this in clean Pythonic code.  I can live with the tuple above but it isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, just add the new key when creating a new list, eg:

```
John = ['smith', 'brown', 'wilson']
Details = [{'age': 23, 'hometown': 'chicago'},{'age': 26, 'hometown': 'New York'}, {'age': 44, 'hometown': 'Boston'}]

combined = [dict(detail, John=surname) for detail, surname in zip(Details, John)]
# [{'hometown': 'chicago', 'age': 23, 'John': 'smith'}, {'hometown': 'New York', 'age': 26, 'John': 'brown'}, {'hometown': 'Boston', 'age': 44, 'John': 'wilson'}]
```

Comment: Or use `detail.update` if you want to alter the original `detail`s objects.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware you could add the key name like that using dict.  Perfect!

Comment: @Marcin, update returns `None` so how would you use it in a comprehension?

Comment: @alancalvitti It modifies the original dict so it doesn't matter what the result of the comprehension is. You could just use a loop.

Comment: @Marcin, comprehensions were added to avoid using loops (where possible).

Comment: @alancalvitti What's the difference between a loop and a comprehension?

Comment: @Marcin, comprehensions are not as general because can only include expressions, not statements (eg, assignment) but are encouraged b/c of simplicity and returns a list (or dict, tuple, set), so it's a functional approach.

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda john,detail: dict(detail, John=john), John, Details)

>>>[{'hometown': 'chicago', 'age': 23, 'John': 'smith'}, 
    {'hometown': 'New York', 'age': 26, 'John': 'brown'},
    {'hometown':'Boston', 'age': 44, 'John': 'wilson'}]
```